# why "true || undefined ? undefined : false;" returns "undefinied"?

Tags: javascript

I wrote this expression in chrome console:

```
true || undefined ? undefined : false;
```

and it returned:

```
undefined
```

How come?
[image]

Comment: ```true || undefined``` is always true. so ```true || undefined ? undefined : false;``` is undefined

Comment: because true or undefined is true, an if true it returns undefined

Comment: You *asked* it to return "undefined "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition (`true || undefined`) is `true`, hence, the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) will take `undefined` as the result:

```js
const condition = true || undefined;
console.log("condition:", condition);

console.log("result:", condition ? undefined : false);
```

If your goal is to split by the `||`:

```js
const result = true || (undefined ? undefined : false);

console.log("result:", result);
```

Answer (score 2):

`||` is higher precedence than `?:`, making the expression equivalent to `(true || undefined) ? undefined : false;`. Thus, it evaluates `true || undefined` first, which evaluates to `true`, then chooses the truthy side of the `:`, `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

the expression is equivalent to:

```
if (true) {
  return undefined;
} else if (undefined) {
  return undefined;
} else {
  return false;
}
```

so it's return the first `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like this:

```
function IsSomething(bool){
    return bool || bool === undefined;
}
```

The problem with "true || undefined" is that the answer to this is undefined, which is why you are seeing undefined returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
true or <literally any other value>
```

...is always true.

“Or” statements return the first true item they encounter, if one is present. “And” statements return the last true item if present.